# Regex for matching only first of two same characters in a string

Tags: javascript, regex

I have these two strings: `"1-2"` and `"1--2"`.

I would like to have a regex that would match only the first occurrence of the hyphen in both strings, such that the split would then be: `[1,2]` and `[1,-2]`. How would I achieve this, since I have been wracking my brain for too long on this now?

EDIT: The two strings can also occur in the same string such that: `"1-2-1--2"`. Therefore a single regular expression covering both cases would be in order.

Comment: What is expected output for `"1-2-1--2"` ?

Comment: The expected output is`[1,2,1,-2]`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use this `split` with a word boundary before `-`:

```js
let s='1-2-1--2'
let arr = s.split(/\b-/)

console.log(arr)
//=> [1, 2, 1, -2)
```

Comment: Apologies, I have clarified my original question to explain that both strings can be contained in one string, and as such a single regular expression is in order.

Comment: Simple and sweet, I did not think of this one bit. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Keep in mind that this only works as long as the character before the dash is a word boundary. If you have the string `'1-2-1+--2'.split(/\b-/) //=> [ "1", "2", "1+--2" ]`.

Comment: @JohanWentholt Ah, that's good to know indeed. In my case that situation cannot happen thankfully, but definitely nice to know!

Comment: If JavaScript had better regex support you could just use a negative lookbehind `/(?<!-)-/`.

Comment: Indeed, if only. It's something that has always bugged me.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're looking for something like this:

```
(-?[0-9]+)-(-?[0-9]+)
```

where the first and the second group could have a negative sign

UPDATE: 
based on your edit, this implementation would do the job:

```js
var str = '-1--2-2--34-1';
var regex = /(-?\d+)-?/g;
var matches = [];
while((match = regex.exec(str))) {
    matches.push(match[1]);
}
console.log(matches);
```

I prefer using split, but it's fine if you only want to use RegEx.

Answer (score 1):

You can use simple `split()`, but with replacement. For example,

```js
var str = '1-2-1--2';

var numArr = str.replace(/--/g, '-~') // The tilde (~) have no mean, this is a charceter for mark a negative number
  .split('-')
  .map(function(n) { return Number(n.replace('~', '-')); });

console.log(numArr);
```

Comment: This indeed is something I was thinking of doing as a last resort, but turns out there indeed is a very simple way to do this.

Comment: Replacing and splitting is in my opinion a perfectly fine solution, however the above seems a bit cumbersome. Let's assume the NULL character isn't used in the text. We could just `'1-2-1--2'.replace(/-(-*)/g, "\0$1").split("\0") //=> [ "1", "2", "1", "-2" ]`.

Comment: @JohanWentholt Why do you need `(-*)`, when there isn't more than one dash?

Comment: @ChayimFriedman You are correct, it can also be changed to `(-?)`, but I thought I might as well make it more generic.